# Getting rid of extra spaces between components when the JFrame is resized

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using the GridBagLayout to arrange some components in a frame.

When the frame is first created, the components have a decent space in between them.[image]

But as soon as I resize the frame there are alot of unwanted space between the components
[image]

I tried adjusting the weights and insets as suggested by some users, but it does not seem to fix the problem

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame {

    JLabel one = new JLabel("one");
    JLabel two = new JLabel("two");
    JLabel three = new JLabel("three");

    JTextField oneF = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField twoF = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField threeF = new JTextField(20);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    public Frame1() {
        setTitle("GridBagLayout Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        menuBar.add(menu);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = c.REMAINDER;
        c.fill = c.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(menuBar, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(one, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(oneF, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(two, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(twoF, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(three, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = c.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        add(threeF, c);

       //setResizable(false);
       pack();
       setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

ps:- I am new to GUI programming, so please forgive me for any noob mistakes.

edit 1: This is the what I want to have after I am done. I know the currently it does not look anyway near what I have in mind... I am still working on it[image]

Thanks

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and with more width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to add empty row / columns that will grow to fill the available space:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame {

    JLabel one = new JLabel("one");
    JLabel two = new JLabel("two");
    JLabel three = new JLabel("three");

    JTextField oneF = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField twoF = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField threeF = new JTextField(20);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");

    public Frame1() {

        setTitle("GridBagLayout Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0}; //this defines 4 rows
        //make 2 last empty row grow 
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0,1.0};

        //do the same for columns 
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0,1.0};

        getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        menuBar.add(menu);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.fill = c.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = c.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0);
        getContentPane().add(menuBar, c);

        //better have a new GridBagConstraints for each component added 
        GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 1;
        c1.gridwidth = 1;
        c1.fill = c1.NONE;
        c1.anchor = c1.NORTH;
        c1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        getContentPane().add(one, c1);

        GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        c2.gridx = 1;
        c2.gridy = 1;
        c2.fill = c2.NONE;
        c2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        c2.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        getContentPane().add(oneF, c2);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame1();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** in response to your edit: use the additional "growing" column for the "cover art"

Comment: I just ran your code. I think I can work with this, but can you please explain what you have done after creating the gridBagLayout. I am having a hard time understanding what you did there.
Thanks

Comment: And how did you make the components not resizable and set them in one place?
Thanks

Comment: I added some comments. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

- use an nested layout (combinations of a few `LayoutManager`s), your picture talks me about,
- still you can use `GridBagLayout` for components placed into left side,
- in my code (simplest idea as is possible) `JComponent`s placed on left side can't be resizable because are restricted from LayoutManager`s defaults, more in [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

[image]

.

[image]

.

painted from SSCCE/MCVE

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Whatever");
    private JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public Color getBackground() {
            return new Color(255, 000, 000);
        }
    };
    private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(/*default is FlowLayout*/) {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(300, 400);
                }

                @Override
                public Color getBackground() {
                    return new Color(255, 255, 000);
                }
            };
    private JPanel leftChildPanel = new JPanel() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public Color getBackground() {
            return new Color(255, 255, 225);
        }
    };
    private JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 380);
        }

        @Override
        public Color getBackground() {
            return new Color(000, 255, 225);
        }
    };

    public MyFrame() {
        parentPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        leftPanel.add(leftChildPanel);
        parentPanel.add(rightPanel);
        myFrame.add(parentPanel);
        myFrame.setLocation(150, 150);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MyFrame();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried the way you suggested and it fixes the vertical spacing between all components. However, The spacing between the two column is wider than before (using a GridBagLayout in a panel). Is there anyway I could fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `JComponents` returns its `getPreferredSize` back to container (e.g. `JPanel`) and `LayoutManager` can recalculating that differently, for example in my code example is reduced `JPanel`s dimension by forces `public Dimension getPreferredSize() {`

Comment: (couldn't be confortable for newbee) you have to use custom MigLayout in the case that you want to use only one JPanel, then there you are able to set various methods

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your assignments of `c.weightx` and `c.weighty`.  weightx and weighty determine how extra space is allocated to grid cells in a GridBagLayout when the container is made larger than necessary to accommodate the preferred sizes of the components.

The weightx and weighty should be zero for all cells except those cells which you want to grow larger when the window is made larger.

Answer (score 1):

I have no real idea on how it is supposed to look like, but you could try to set for the labels `c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST` and `c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST` for the textfields.

Try also setting `c.fill = GridBadConstraints.BOTH`.

Comment: is it possible to set all of the components in the top left side even if the frame is resized? Thanks

Comment: The top left side would be c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST